# Induction on an if-then statement

Tags: induction

So we are told to do induction on this statement:

**"Let P(n) be the statement: If a + n = c + n, then a = b."**, and I am told to induct on n, so I do.

Base: Let P(0) be the statement : "If a + 0 = c + 0, then a = b". which is true.

From there, you assume P(n) to be true for n (denoted n'). However, I'm stuck on how to go on from here as well as what my inductive hypothesis is.

Thanks all!

Comment: Your induction hypothesis is that $a+n = b+n$ implies $a=b$ and you want to show that $a+n+1 = b+n+1$ implies $a=b$. But what are you working with? Is addition commutative? Can't you just subtract $n$?

Comment: @57Jimmy Subtracting n is really adding -n. So this would amount to arguing that adding -n to both sides preserves the equality. But "adding the same thing to both sides of equation preserves the equality" is precisely what's being asked to prove.

Comment: @Acccumulation I most certainly agree, but since the OP put "algebraic number theory" as a tag, I was just wondering what he was possibly trying to do.

Comment: Your title is rather generic; induction is generally used to show that a property always follows from certain conditions, so "induction" and "if then" is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you're trying to do a proof, you need to look at what your premises are. If you're trying to prove this in Peano arithmetic, then you have the axiom that (a = b) => (a+1=b+1). So if (a+n)=(b+n), then (a+n)+1=(b+n)+1, and by associativity a+(n+1)=b+(n+1).